# Cocos2d-x 2.2.5 scene replacing

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Recently i started to study Cocos2d-x (C++). Problem is following, i do not know what is my problem, when i try to change scenes(when push the but).

```
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::CCObject* pSender)
{
CCScene *pScene = UzdevumsScene::scene();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(pScene);
}
```

Error:

```
error: undefined reference to 'UzdevumsScene::scene()'
```

When i use this line, i get nothing more than black screen(when i push the button).

```
CCScene *UzdevumsScene = CCScene::create();
    CCTransitionPageTurn *HelloWorld = CCTransitionPageTurn::create(1, UzdevumsScene, true);
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(UzdevumsScene);
```

Comment: What is UzdevumsScene ? Maybe, you don't include .h file.

Comment: @AndreKirpitchz UdevumsScene=TaskScene, only in Latvian language. I have include .h file. Maybe i will post full code.

Comment: Problem was in Android.mk file. When i declared UzdevumsScene in Android.mk, scene replacing started to work.